# stringstream doesn't accept white space?

Tags: c++, g++

I have the following code:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << 1 << "a b c";
std::string result;
ss >> result;
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

I see "1a" instead of "1a b c".

I read somewhere that I should have ss << std::noskip.  But it doesn't help.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `getline` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
std::getline(ss, result);
```

or, just get `string`

```
result = ss.str();
```

Comment: I had trouble with `std::noskipws` a while ago and I did not find the documentation clear enough so I'd go with `getline`.

Comment: noskipws does not affect strings the way you think. `1a` will still be read instead of the line. The difference comes in case when the stream begins with a space. if you input `  aa bb cc` then without `noskipws` `aa` will be read, with noskipws -empty string!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try using this for getting whitespace in string
    string input;
    cout<<"\nInput : "<<input;
    getline(cin,input);
    string result,label;
    std::stringstream sstr(input);
    while(sstr>>label){
        result=result+label+" ";
    }
cout<<"\nResult : "<<result;
```