# White space insertion in std::stringstream fails

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, stringstream

I'm trying to insert white space in std::stringstream in this way.

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr.str("");
sstr << " ";
sstr << 10;
```

and then setting it as a label like that

```
label->setString(sstr.str().c_str());
```

but it's only giving me 10, space is not included. I've followed many links to solve problem but of no use. Following link suggests to use getline() but in my case I cannot do that :

> [stringstream doesn't accept white space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935026/stringstream-doesnt-accept-white-space)

I've also tried to use **std::noskipws** but it also not work :

```
sstr << std::noskipws << " ";
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to write the 10 as string: sstr << "10";

Comment: Perhps try doing `sstr << " 10";`

Comment: I want it as integer, they are not insertable?

Comment: Works for me: http://cpp.sh/8d6

Comment: Probably has something to do with your editor, because the space should appear like it does [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/05dc97b64acc73a3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::stringstream` should not remove your whitespace when used like this. Are you sure that it is not the label-object that is trimming your string and removing the whitespace?

Try debugging or printing out your string before setting it to the label.

Comment: You are right @Tafuri , **label->setString(" 10")** is trimming space.Still could not figure out why!

Answer (score 1):

You can use put method to append a single char:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr.str("");
sstr.put(' ');
sstr.put(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using it wrong:

```
string labelstr;
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr.str("");
sstr << " ";
sstr << 10;
ss >> noskipws >> labelstr;
label->setString(labelstr);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/

Comment: This seems more like an answer to the linked question?

Comment: It's when we are extracting from stringstream, when inserting we've to use >>.

Comment: Yes, but the op did not extract the streams string using stream operator (which is where the whitespace in the other question got eaten).

Comment: `noskipws` is a flag you're using when you want to extract text from the stream. It's not like you set it beforehand..

Comment: Yes, but the better way to extract the string is to use the `.str()` function which is what OP is doing already.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I agree with you on this. You should use `.str()`. But I suggested this answer as a fail-safe version to see if it works. If it doesn't there must be a serious problem somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected for me. Here's a runnable example: http://cpp.sh/8d6.

The culprit must be `setString` trimming your input. Or possibly some other function that reads the string later.